# Best practice for reusable calculations on data in redux store

Tags: model, reactjs, redux

I've just finished wiring up a redux app, and it's fantastic so far. However, because state is stored in a giant store, you don't have any models that you're accessing your data from.

Let's say I have a model class that stores some information about a user. I'd usually add a function to the class called `display_name` that combines the different parts of their name intelligently. With that, my different views could simply call `display_name` instead of them needing to know how to calculate it themselves.

Redux explicitly says not to store calculated values in the state, so that leaves it to being defined in the components. This can't possibly be right though, because then you'd end up duplicating this code in every component that needs it.

Where is the proper place to store this logic?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest method is to create utility functions to calculate this data and put them in a separate module that can be used by many components' `mapStateToProps` functions. A super-simple example:

```js
import { displayName } from "./utils";

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    displayName: displayName(state.user)
  };
}

function MyComponent(props) {
  return <div>Name: {props.displayName}</div>;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Computing Derived Data](http://rackt.org/redux/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html) page in the Redux docs, the suggested approach is using the [Reselect](https://github.com/rackt/reselect) library for handling selection and memoization.

If you search Github for Javascript projects that contain the term "createSelector", you should find a number of actual apps that are using Reselect in various ways.  Here's three that I turned up: [jfurrow/flood](https://github.com/jfurrow/flood), [FH-Potsdam/shifted maps](https://github.com/FH-Potsdam/shifted-maps), and [madou/GW2 Armory](https://github.com/madou/gw2armory.com)

Comment: I feel like this is the correct answer, the answer, as the accepted answer would result in a re-compute every time.

Comment: Totally depends on what the `displayName` function returns. If it's a string, then re-creating the string with the same contents every time is still considered `===` equal.