# Redux vs. Traditional MVC

Tags: javascript, flux, redux

In regular MVC, it's a common pattern to have "getter" methods on a model that compute commonly derived data. For example:

```
class User {
   var firstName;
   var lastName;

   getFullName() {
     return firstName + " " + lastName;
   }
}
```

Let's assume the server JSON response is {'firstName': "Bob", 'lastName': "Smith"}.

In regular Flux, you could place such a method (getFullName()) on your store (for example, Alt solves this by allowing you to use an "exportPublicMethods" on your store).

In Redux, I'm not sure where that "getFullName()" method would live, considering it's encouraged to use regular javascript objects inside your states (i.e. in my example, only firstName and lastName would be stored, with no easy way to generate the derived full name).

What would be the best / easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this answer will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34255100/best-practice-for-reusable-calculations-on-data-in-redux-store

Comment: Hi, I've just published this library a react state manager oriented MVC. It uses Redux API to work, and saves you a bunch of redundant code, here is the project repo:
https://github.com/Fantasim/react-ascey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html), a concept called a "selector" is used to map raw API data to the representation desired in the view. This is specifically for use with [react-redux](https://github.com/rackt/react-redux), but you could certainly use the same technique with any given view layer.